# output an image with php script - src tag

Tags: php, image, src

I cannot output images on my web page on local host,

I am using an images.php script, the last part is;

```
if ($mime) { 
           header('Content-type: '.$mime); 
           header('Content-length: '.filesize($pic)); 
           $file = @ fopen($pic, 'rb'); 
           if ($file) { 
                      fpassthru($file); 
                      exit;
                      }
           }
```

My other php page includes the below code;

```
<li><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank"><img src="images.php?key=orn"></a></li>
```

However, all my images like the above are broken, I debugged my images.php file with if&else's and I saw that it comes to the end with true variables.

How can I find the reason?

fpassthru? grammer of src? localhost? any other thing?

Comment: Try to echo file_get_contents($pic); to see if your script can open the image and so you can see the content.
If not, it may be a right issue (chmod +rx * on the img folder)

Comment: You ignore errors by adding `@`. Remove it and see error log (or errors in page)

Comment: So you are debugging by opening `images.php?key=orn` in the browser directly, yes?

Comment: @Koren I couldn't get the image with echo file_get_contents($pic);
I am taking some charcters of two lines when I send the query via browser's address bar.
Files were on cloud, I placed the folders onto desktop, even an image directly on desktop, didn't open, I am using mac, how can/should I apply chmod?

Comment: @u_mulder I removed @, nothing changed, I didn't take any extra error, actually I checked that it comes to the fpassthru line, if fopen failed, wouldn't $file be false? Is there some error log necessary to look at?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Yes, I am debugging by openning the query in the browser directly,
I am using Firefox, but also checked on Chrome.

Comment: I uploaded the files into the web server to see the result, I can view the images with direct path, but cannot view those with php script, I could view none on the local server, actually I wrote the script just to be able to output images after converting all site to php, I can ignore the querystring but why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = '../image.jpg';
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

You can also look into mod_xsendfile

Comment: I tried readfile(), but didn't work, 

I read about mod_xsendfile that it deals with bigger files against PHP’s max execution time limit and memory limit, but one of my image is 4 kb.

Comment: if it didn't work its probably your path to the image ($file variable).  Try using an absolute path.  Also the above assumes you are using a jpeg file...if it is different change it but keep it hardcoded for now to eliminate any change of mime detection causing issues